# Cannot get Eclipse IDE to run

Tags: eclipse, java, java-7

I'm trying to install Eclipse IDE Classic.

I've unzipped the folder and it's on my Desktop. I double click on the eclipse.exe file and I had a Java error so within the eclipse.ini file I changed my JDK location as follows:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
```

Now, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

My JDK is up to datem I've updated it and even tried a fresh install.
I've also tried other Eclipse IDE versions and searched the net for this problem yet I can't find a solution which works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my eclipse.ini file there is no space between the -vm and the directory of the vm.  I remember reading something about this before, worth giving it a shot.

`-vmC:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe`

Comment: Based on the documentation it says this : The -vm option and its value (the path) must be on separate lines.

Comment: Interesting.  I just checked out the link in your answer.  I wonder why my config works even though it is not compliant, maybe it is programmed with some leniency.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help. It is kind of interesting that this solution went against established documentation, I can't recall where I read this, but it stuck with me as I have worked with Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Thnaks Duncan Krebs, your solution worked for me!
I changed from

```
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\javaw.exe
```

to

```
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\javaw.exe
```

and it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

This is because your eclipse.ini is not correctly configured. Most likely it is because you are adding the param in the wrong place in the file here is an example. I'm not sure if you need a % for the space in program files I would suggest having a filepath to your jdk that does not have any spaces. Make sure the vm is specified before vm arguments otherwise you will get the error you are getting. Look here for an example to follow [Eclipse INI Configuration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)  towards the bottom of the page.